# dbcc checkdb equivalent for SQL Azure?

Tags: azure-sql-database

dbcc checkdb is useful in checking for consistency errors in SQL Server, however it is not supported by SQL Azure.

Is there another approach to checking for consistency errors in a SQL Azure instance? I am also looking for monitoring tools that may provide record numbers, the sort of data that Standard Reports provides for an on-premise DB.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1

Just saw an interesting quote on this:

"One that is both great and worrisome, you no longer have to worry about consistency checks. You can’t run consistency checks."

Surely one still needs to monitor this? The fact that you seem to unable to do so is of concern to me.

EDIT 2

I found this free gem called "Orphan Finder", see:[Orphan Finder Website](http://www.spi.hr/ZaITprofesionalce/OrphanFinder/tabid/356/Default.aspx) It also analyses SQL Azure Databases. To my pleasant surprise I had no issues, but I now have a tool to monitor the issue with. I would still be interested in other monitoring tools. Also I have been checking out Cotega and New Relic.

Answer (score 1):

Dbcc checkdb is supported in sql azure db v12 and you don't need any other explicit tool for this,